# ACM Digital Library template: CCS Concepts are causing overlapping text

Tags: acm

I consider myself somewhat of an end-user when it comes to LaTeX, so please bear with me here. I'm using the ACM template files found at http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template .

In the template file, they expect me to classify my work by generating CCS Codes using the tool found at dl.acm.org/ccs.cfm.

The generated CCS code looks like this in my .tex file:

```
\begin{CCSXML}
    <ccs2012>
    <concept>
    <concept_id>10003120.10003121.10003128.10011755</concept_id>
    <concept_desc>Human-centered computing~Gestural input</concept_desc>
    <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
    </concept>
    <concept>
    <concept_id>10010147.10010371.10010387.10010866</concept_id>
    <concept_desc>Computing methodologies~Virtual reality</concept_desc>
    <concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
    </concept>
    </ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Human-centered computing~Gestural input}
\ccsdesc[300]{Computing methodologies~Virtual reality}

\printccsdesc
```

However, upon building, the generated .pdf file looks like this:
[image: Overlap]

If I switch the two concepts around (which I don't think is allowed since they should be sorted by significance), I get this:
[image]

Is there anything I could do to maintain the order, yet stop the overlap?

Comment: i fixed the link.  you could probably have done it yourself.  two things were needed: the `http://` at the beginning, and a space at the end before the period.  if the period is "attached", a very nice "404" page comes up.

Comment: since the coding is in xml, i'd be inclined to try inserting `<br>` between the end of the first and the beginning of the second.  might not work, but worth trying, i think.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately stackexchange does not allow me to create more than 2 links without sufficient reputation, so I used my 2-link quota on the images instead, so I appreciate the fix. Secondly, inserting <br> does not work unfortunately. The \ccsdesc[...] part is what actually generates the text, and not the xml itself.

Comment: another hackish suggestion then.  try putting `\newline` after the first `\ccsdesc`.  that says to leave the first line short, but that seems better than having the overrun.

Comment: Adding a `\newline` as you say results in the error: _there is no line here to end..._. If I instead add it within the curly braces I get a somewhat favourable result as seen in [http://i.imgur.com/flyN2Ix.jpg]. Which in your opinion is the lesser of the two evils? Switching the concepts around or having that semicolon in the middle of nowhere?

Comment: urk!  i assume you're going to be submitting this for publication.  and i further assume that the editors are actually going to look at what you submit.  i've looked at the `.cls` file, and i know the latest maintainer.  i'll send him an inquiry.  (i'm thinking of the `\nopunct` facility in the ams document classes.  this might be used profitably in such cases, though not necessarily directly; the technique might be incorporated into a "break this line" suitable for splitting up the concepts in a case such as this.)

Comment: one other approach suggests itself.  although not wonderful, it may be possible to force hyphenation with a discretionary hyphen: `Com\-puting methodologies`.  try that and see if anything useful happens.

Comment: Alright. Unfortunately the submission date is soon, and I was kinda hoping for a quick-fix. I truly do appreciate the support, but I may need to make a choice soon and hope that the editors forgive me for my sacrilegious acts. I'll hang around for another few minutes to see if there's a reply though! (In hindsight I should've included the CCS Concepts much earlier...)

Comment: Alrighty. Seems it works if I go co-mputing methodologies (the backslash causes errors). See the result here: http://i.imgur.com/egJGXiR.jpg . It's a lot better than what I had, so I really appreciate your input!

Comment: In hindsight it's probably better to break the word at the syllable (i.e. com-puting as you suggested)

Comment: two acceptable syllabic break points: "com-put-ing".  sadly, the class is written in such a way that there's not a quick "code" fix.  but now the last named maintainer knows about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest setting the codes ragged right for this particular case

```
{\raggedright\printccsdesc\par}
```